# Forgotten Book Title - space sci-fi within solar system

Tags: story-identification, novel, space

I recall a book I read 15-20 years ago about a rich businessman with company interests in space. Some government, (or his state-backed competitors) kept interfering with his interests, so he raided their space station/ship with his own as a ‘privateer’.

He was sort of an Elon Musk figure (long before Elon was round). Novel celebrated capitalism and entrepreneurship in a big way. Perhaps written during the Cold War (those kind of vibes).

I recall it as a paperback with a silver cover and a picture (I think) of a spaceship on it.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like Heinlein to me, though offhand I don't remember one of his novels with exactly that plot.

Comment: The "Venus Equilateral" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_Equilateral) collection has one or two stories that vaguely fit ("Recoil" and "Firing Line", the latter probably more than the former), but does not really fit the timeline (it is pretty unmistakably from the 1940s). The Orbit books edition is silver with a spaceship (https://www.amazon.de/Venus-Equilateral-v-Orbit-Books/dp/0860078604).

Comment: I agree John, I was thinking The Man who sold the Moon although I can't recall the 'privateer' angle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Sold_the_Moon

Comment: Perhaps a long shot, but maybe H. Beam Piper's *Space Viking*? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Viking

Answer (score 9):

Possibly the *Sam Gunn* series by Ben Bova.

Collected in *The Sam Gunn Omnibus* (2007, collecting 2 books from 1997 - 1998)

[image]

> A hero without peer or scruples, Sam Gunn has a nose for trouble,
> money, and women--though not necessarily in that order. A man with the
> ego (and stature) of a Napoleon, the business acumen of a P. T.
> Barnum, and the raging hormones of a teenage boy, Sam is the finest
> astronaut NASA ever trained…and dumped.
>
> But more than money, more than women, Sam Gunn loves justice. (And he
> really does love money and women.) Whether he's suing the Pope,
> helping twin sisters entangled in the "virtual sex" trade, or on trial
> for his life on charges of interplanetary genocide, you can be sure of
> one this is one space jockey who'll meet every challenge with a smile
> on his lips, an ace up his sleeve…and a weapon in his pocket.